# Multimaster LDAP replication on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, ldif

I'm attempting to setup a multimaster pair on Ubuntu 11.04. I currently have a working single server which I've cloned to a 2nd server. The installed version of OpenLDAP is the default from the Ubuntu apt repos -  2.4.23-6ubuntu6.1.

It seems that slapd.conf has recently been deprecated and it's now necessary to put configuration into the LDAP db itself.

I've found a couple of references to do that for a master->slave setup, but not for a multimaster config.

Does anyone have a good example of an LDIF I can pinch and modify please?

Regards....

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Here you are http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/replication.html, although a bit late :D